# Prototype pattern (calling function)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying my hand at using Addy Osmani's prototype pattern.

I have an object "app" and, upon a submission of a form, I'm trying to call a function inside of my init function. But it isn't console.logging...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var app = {

        logHello: function() {
            console.log('hello');
        },



        initialize: function() {           

            $('#userlogin').on('submit', function(){
                this.logHello;
                return false;
            });

        }

    }

    app.initialize();
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Inside a jQuery event handler, `this` refers to the element (explicitly set by jQuery). So `this.logHello`, which would do nothing anyways because you aren't calling anything, refers to something that doesn't exist

Comment: So how would I remedy the 'this' error then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is now referring to your jQuery `on submit` function, try using a context variable of `this` (also, you need `()` after you call your function):

```
var self = this;
$('#userlogin').on('submit', function(){
    self.logHello();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/59Y9z/

Answer (score 3):

```
  initialize: function() {           
            var self=this;
            $('#userlogin').on('submit', function(){
                self.logHello();
                return false;
            });

        }
```

this keyword changes according to the function scope, a function in another function creates a new scope ,unless it is bound to a scope somehow.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue of scope. Within the submit event handler, the `this` variable refers to the function's scope and not the scope of `app` where your `logHello` function resides.

Try something like this :

```
...
initialize: function() {
  var old_scope = this; // save the scope into a local variable
  $( '#userlogin' ).on( 'submit' , function() {
    old_scope.logHello;
    return false;
  });
},
...
```

The variable `old_scope` will now contain the scope of `app`, so you'll be able to access all of the variable and functions that `app` holds.